# Moving a blade server to another C7000 enclosure

Tags: hp, hp-proliant, blade-server

I need to move a Bl460c G7 blade to another C7000 enclosure.  The server is attached to a D2700 SAS direct attached storage through a 6GB SAS Switches which are also inserted in old C7000.  I need to know if the server's RAID controller, the SAS switch and D2700 will retain RAID configuration after I move them to another C7000.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The RAID configuration is stored on disk in Smart Array controller setups. You won't lose your configuration unless you explicitly alter the RAID configuration (e.g. [deleting a logical drive](https://serverfault.com/questions/470570/accidentally-deleted-wrong-logical-drive-hp-smart-array-p800-controller))

I would move the blade server, then the SAS interconnect and make sure they're recognized.  Once that's confirmed, then I'd attach the D2700 enclosure.