# Data recovery from deleted raid array

Tags: raid, hp, hp-proliant, hp-smart-array

Hello I deleted a raid 1 array on a hp b110i and I wanted to know if it is possible to recover the data.  Also if Windows server was on the array that was deleted can it be recovered.

Thanks

Comment: How did you delete the array?

Comment: Through the array management bios at startup, it was on a dl 160 g6

Comment: Did you recreate the array or take any other actions following the deletion of the array?

Comment: No, no other action has been taken

Answer (score 3):

It's possible to recover the data, provided no other actions have been taken on the array. You could do a few things like taking an image of the individual disks (via Clonezilla/dd/etc.) and keeping that as a fallback...

The common approach is to try to either recreate the array with the same settings/RAID/level/strip size and boot via a recovery CD to extract the data...

Or you can try powering the server off completely and booting with one disk inserted to see if the array metadata is present or recognized. You may have an option to press `F2` to try array recovery.

Also see: [Accidentally deleted wrong logical drive HP Smart Array P800 controller](https://serverfault.com/questions/470570/accidentally-deleted-wrong-logical-drive-hp-smart-array-p800-controller/470582#470582)

But I have to add, the process of deleting a logical drive on HP controllers asks for [a double confirmation](http://h20566.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.PAGE/public/kb/docDisplay/?sp4ts.oid=3346452&spf_p.tpst=kbDocDisplay&spf_p.prp_kbDocDisplay=wsrp-navigationalState%3DdocId%253Demr_na-c01479524-6%257CdocLocale%253D%257CcalledBy%253D&javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken). What were you trying to do?

Comment: Well actually, I was just checking

Comment: As The server contained exchange and it was stolen by the arrays were deleted

Comment: Btw, this is just an exercise, in case it ever happens

Comment: @user2352274 If you need security against theft of the drives, you need encryption.

Answer (score 1):

I did same mistake few months ago, deleted array on wrong server (ProLiant ML110 G7 with Smart Array B110i).

6 easy steps:

1. Do byte-by-byte backup of first mirror.
2. Recreate logical drive. Good thing of that recreation in my case was that it didn't resync physical disks. It touched only beginning of the disk, messed up partition table. Windows MFT and files **were** untouched.
3. If drive logical drive resync itself, recover data from the mirror's backup.
4. Use [sysresccd](http://www.sysresccd.org/Download) and run so called `testdisk` utility, choose first disk if there will be only one, right partition format, most likely it's *Intel/PC partition* or *EFI GPT partition* if there was Windows Server installed. Then choose analyse, testdisk will find lost partition table, chose it and write changes to disk. After disk step Windows should try to boot, you will see Windows logo and shortly after that BSOD.
5. Last thing to do is repair Boot sector and Windows Boot Manager, boot partition will change its ID and it'll prevent Windows from boot. You need current Windows CD to do that, make sure it has raid controller drivers inside it. [Guide](http://www.thomasmaurer.ch/2011/01/add-drivers-to-windows-installation-iso/). Then you need to repair boot manager for example using this [guide](http://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/04/SLN167714/EN).
6. If you had only one disk in `testdisk` you can skip this step. The thing is to resync array again after system repair, if you made to point  that it (the system) boots correctly. You can achieve this by hot removing 2nd mirror, and plugging it again. Smart Array should force drives to resync.